# How to programmatically create a static styled MaterialButton?

Tags: android, material-design

**Goal**

How to programmatically create a `MaterialButton` with a custom `style` resources instead of `attr`?

**styles.xml**

```
 <style name="CustomButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
 </style>
```

I have tried with the following, but it is not working as expected (the button will fallback to `R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_Button` no matter which `style` were provided).

```
 MaterialButton button = new MaterialButton(context, null, R.style.CustomButtonStyle);
```

**Note**

I do **NOT** wish to create a custom theme attribute and pass it like so `new MaterialButton(context, null, R.attr.CustomButtonStyle);`

Tried with material-components-android `1.2.0-alpha05` and `1.1.0`

Comment: The 3rd parameter **isn't** a style. It is an attribute in the app theme like the `materialButtonStyle`.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti if thats the case, how can I pass a style?